# How to implement virtual mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, datagridview

While exploring `Virtual Mode` its seem to be very useful.
One way to Call large amount of data is to use `Pagging` by calling the records required per page in datagridview.

I want to explore `how much amount of data could efficiently be loaded in datagridview`.
I have **DB  Tables** with record over **10k**, if these are loaded in a list it will cause **server time out**.

Comment: Your title says Winforms and your tag refers to WPF datagrid. Which one is it, WPF or Winforms?

Comment: sorry windows form in hurry i mistaken just editing know

Comment: Added the c# and winforms as metadata tags instead. This should help you get more attention.

Comment: There is a [Walkhrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx) available i MSDN. It might help you.